# Altering registered symbols (R)

Tags: jquery

Would it be possible with jQuery to find in all symbols that are written with

```
&reg;
```

and wrap them with a sup tag?

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Comment: Where? the whole page? a string?

Comment: If it would be a performance issue, it would be nice to specify sections like div#content or something of the sort.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? Why can't you run a find and replace either through sql/content files?

Comment: Nope. I need something that is easy to implement and would be used on multiple environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var replaced = $('body').html().replace('&reg;', '<sup>&reg;</sup>');
$('body').html(replaced);
```

Comment: Of course, using `html` will remove all `.data` and attached event handlers, so it is better to do it on elements that contain only text.