# Change CSS of a certain character in a specific div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to change the CSS of a single character on a complete page:

E.g.

I have few divs on my page

```
<div class="a">
abcd
</div>
<div class="b">
abcd
</div>
<div class="c">
abcd
</div>
<div class="d">
abcd
</div>
```

And I want to change CSS of character "d" but only in div that belongs to class "c"

Is there a way to do that.

P.S. I want to change the font of that one single character

Comment: you can't directly to it, but if you wrap the `d` in a `<span>`, you can put the styles on the span. so, yes you can, but you'll have to do some DOM modifications.

Comment: Is there just text inside the divs?

Comment: @AlexW Yes there is just text inside the div's that I want this feature for

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply a style to a single special HTML character across the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841205/how-to-apply-a-style-to-a-single-special-html-character-across-the-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Chrome:

```
var Cs = document.getElementsByClassName('c');

for(var i = 0; i < Cs.length; i++)
{
    var text = Cs[i].textContent;
    Cs[i].innerHTML = text.replace('d','<span class="red">d</span>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5ZC8/

Comment: @kapilchhattani If you want to support IE8 or below, just change `textContent` to `innerHTML`. And note that this will work if the div contains text and only text.

Comment: I might add something else soon to the div, like few more tags inside it, what will happen after that..

Answer (score 2):

My approach (You can shorten/optimize code. This code is very detailed for explanation):

```
// config
var string = 'd';
var selector = '.c';
var font_size = 28;

// create regex from string
var regex = new RegExp(string,"g");

// wrap span around string and set font-size
var replace = '<span style="font-size: ' + font_size + 'px;">' + string + '</span>';

// find elements with given selector
var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

    // get HTML from element and ...
    var text = el[i].innerHTML;

    // ... replace it with given span element
    var new_text = text.replace(regex, replace);

    // set new HTML
    el[i].innerHTML = new_text;
};
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopeter/tN3Bx/8/

**Edit**

Sorry, you asked for font-family. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopeter/tN3Bx/9/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find tag which className is c.

```
var class = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
```

Then class is [], so we need to use `for` circulate to find everyone.

```
for (var i = 0, l = Cs.length; i < l; i++) {
    class[i].innerHTML = class[i].innerHTML.replace('d','<span style="color:red">d</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A font can contain a single character customized however you please ([FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/) is your friend):

```css
@font-face { font-family: a; src: url(a); }
@font-face { font-family: b; src: url(b); }
@font-face { font-family: c; src: url(c); }
@font-face { font-family: d; src: url(d); }
.a { font-family: a; }
.b { font-family: b; }
.c { font-family: c; }
.d { font-family: d; }
```