# How to color portion of text using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph of text which has few words inside a special character like %word%. I want to color only these words of paragraph in red. Can I do this in pure css? If not what should be the regex for coloring it through jquery. 
Example:

```
<Html>
 <head>
 <style>
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myelement">
     Hi how do I color %this%? 
  </div>
 </body>
</Html>
```

Comment: Simple way is to surround it using a `span` tag and apply style to it. eg: `Hi how do I color <span style="color:red">this</span>?`

Comment: "How do I do this?" is off-topic.  Since you may have wanted to try, I'll go ahead and proffer a starter.  With one exception I know of, you can't just randomly format letters in a string in HTML - they will need to be wrapped in another element (e.g. `span`).  Try that and if you get stuck, post a specific question.

Comment: These texts are coming dynamically.

Comment: did you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063242/altering-registered-symbols-r ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used regular expression(regex) in `javascript` as follows:

```
function chnColor(){
    var str=document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML;
    str=str.replace(/(%)(.*)(%)/g,"<font color='red'>$2</font>");
    //Here $2 Means Anything in between % and % This is what you need to color 
    document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML=str;
}
```

[## `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/2uN93/1/)

Hope it helps! cheers :)!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.textColor{ color:red; }
</style>
<div id="myelement">
     Hi how do I color <span class="textColor"> %this%?</span> 

</div>
```

in php

```
Hi how do I color <span class="textColor"> <?php echo $text; ?></span>
```

You can use class for specific purpose in css

Comment: The text is not specific, it is coming from a database dynamically.

Comment: in place of "this" you can use variable