# Creating Plugin to Alter TM Symbol Throughout WordPress Site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I found the answer to this [Altering registered symbols (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063242/altering-registered-symbols-r) and I'm trying to implement something similar.

Client doesn't want TM to display with superscript, they want the alternate version where it's displayed as subscript.

I'm trying to create my first WordPress plugin to accomplish this, where it'll take any version of the symbol (symbol, name code, decimal code or hex code) and replace it with the a subscript stylized version).

This is what I've got so far...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Subscript the TM symbol
Plugin URI: TBD
Description: This is my first plugin. Client wants the TM subscript. So I'm    figuring it out. :D
Version: 0.1
Author: Sarah Collins
Author URI: http://sarahcollinsweb.design
*/

( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    $( function () {

        var replaced1 = $('').html().replace('™', '<sub>™</sub>');
        $('').html(replaced1;

    });



    $( function () {

        var replaced2 = $('').html().replace('&trade;', '<sub>&trade;</sub>');
        $('').html(replaced2);

    });


    $( function () {

        var replaced3 = $('').html().replace('&#8482;', '<sub>&#8482;</sub>');
        $('').html(replaced3);

    });


    $( function () {

        var replaced4 = $('').html().replace('&#x2122;', '<sub>&#x2122;</sub>');
        $('').html(replaced4);

    });


}(jQuery));

?>
```

:\ I'm getting a fatal error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that need to be fixed. First, here's the updated version:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Subscript the TM symbol
Plugin URI: TBD
Description: This is my first plugin. Client wants the TM subscript. So I'm    figuring it out. :D
Version: 0.1
Author: Sarah Collins
Author URI: http://sarahcollinsweb.design
*/

add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
      (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var replaced1 = $('body').html().replace('™', '<sub>™</sub>');
          $('body').html(replaced1);

          var replaced2 = $('body').html().replace('&trade;', '<sub>&trade;</sub>');
          $('body').html(replaced2);

          var replaced3 = $('body').html().replace('&#8482;', '<sub>&#8482;</sub>');
          $('body').html(replaced3);

          var replaced4 = $('body').html().replace('&#x2122;', '<sub>&#x2122;</sub>');
          $('body').html(replaced4);
        });
      }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <?
} );
```

And here's the changes:

1. You were mixing PHP and Javascript, and that's no good. Javascript is code that runs in the user's web browser, and so you need to actually *output* that code. In your code above, the PHP interpreter was actually trying to run that JavaScript code, which is definitely not going to work - the answer is to separate things just the tiniest bit, which I'll explain next.
2. Instead, to make your idea work, you must use [WordPress's actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). It's helpful to think of actions as events that occur when WordPress is handling a request and generating a page for a visitor, and WordPress is giving you an opportunity to do something - anything! In this case, you want to add some JavaScript to the `<head>` of the HTML document, and the action you'll want to hook onto is the [`wp_head` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head). (Just FYI, there are dozens of actions that WordPress makes available, and you can even [make your own](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) - this is getting a bit more advanced, however. Suffice to say that this the basic mechanism for WordPress to allow plugins/themes to run custom code.)
3. I simplified your JavaScript code a bit and removed several of the `(function(){}(...))` wrapper; those aren't really doing anything to make your code more efficient. I'm thinking you might've just copied/pasted that as part of what you were building up here, but it's OK to reduce/remove that.
4. Also in the JavaScript, I wrapped your code in the `$(document).ready()` callback; this is so that your code doesn't run *until the page is ready*. This is important, otherwise your code will just run as soon as it's loaded, and that will probably not work exactly right - you should always wait until the document is ready before trying to manipulate the text/html content of the page.

Just as a side note, some folks might point out that this isn't the most efficient way to use jQuery - but I think it's OK to skip over that for now! Mainly just trying to demonstrate how to run JavaScript from a WordPress plugin, so give this a shot and let us know if any issues/questions.